# Axios Post inside loop with changing variable REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have an array of labels for form inputs named **changing_variable**,  which are dependent on what a user selects from a drop down menu, so these are unknown.

I need to be able to let the property of the Axios.post method, equal to the variable in order to input the correct data into my database.
Any examples I see online have properties like:

```
name: this.name
age: this.age
```

However this cannot work for me since I cannot hard code the values since they change depending on the user input, and also there is over a hundred for each user input.

If anyone can help me pass this changing variable to my backend. Thanks

My current code :

```
var i;
var changing_variable;
for(i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
  {

    changing_variable = inputValues[i].text
  Axios.post(URL, changing_variable)
    .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
    console.log(changing_variable)
  })
  }
};
```

**EDIT**
Node.js code

```
app.post('/create', (req,res) => {

const test_variable= req.body.changing_variable;


db.query("INSERT INTO iptable (test_variable) VALUES(?)",

[test_variable], (err,result) =>{

    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else {
        res.send("Values Inserted")
    }
}
)
});
```

**Terminal error message**
code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
errno: 1048,
sqlMessage: "Column 'test_variable' cannot be null",
sqlState: '23000',
index: 0,
sql: 'INSERT INTO iptable (test_variable) VALUES(NULL)'

Comment: This should send the value `inputValues[i].text`, because that is what you assigned to `changing_variable` before you pass the latter into the post method call. What about this exactly is not working? I can't tell what your actual problem is here.

Comment: I have updated the original question to reflect what is going wrong

Comment: `req.body.changing_variable` won't exist, because you sent a plain text value only, not a name=value pair. You would need to provide an object, `{ changing_variable: changing_variable }` - the key being the parameter name, and the value being the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, **URLSearchParams**

By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use the URLSearchParams API.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams({ foo: 'bar' });
params.append('extraparam', 'value');
axios.post('/foo', params);
```

REF https://github.com/axios/axios#urlsearchparams